# How to create a alias of std::tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, std

I am learning C++ and I'd like to know how could create an alias for `std::tuple`.

I want to do what you might do with `std::tuple` but using another name. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename... Args>
using my_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/0Ea3oz)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with [template alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template< class... tupleArgs > using newname = std::tuple< tupleArgs... >;

int main()
{
   newname<int, std::string, double> t1;
   return 0;
}
```

[Simple demo](http://ideone.com/RHk3DZ)